# MongoDB / Meteor: Multiply entire array within collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list, meteor

I have a problem with multiplying an array of key-value pairs in Meteor / MongoDB. I want to multiply an entire ingredient list with a fixed value. The collection looks like this:

```
"ingredients" : [
    {
        "ingredient" : "noodle",
        "amount" : 500,
        "unit" : "g"
    },
    {
        "ingredient" : "cheese",
        "amount" : 100,
        "unit" : "g"
    }
],
```

Now, I want to multiply the **amount** value with a certain number **multip**, let's say 1,5. The desired output would look like:

```
"ingredients" : [
    {
        "ingredient" : "noodle",
        "amount" : 750,
        "unit" : "g"
    },
    {
        "ingredient" : "cheese",
        "amount" : 150,
        "unit" : "g"
    }
],
```

Right now I have this:

```
for (i in this.ingredients){
  var precalc = this.ingredients[i].amount * multip; //Here's the Multiplicator
  var prez=this.ingredients[i].ingredient;
  var prem=this.ingredients[i].unit;
  Recipes.update(
    {"_id": this._id},
    {"$set": {
      "ingredients":[{ingredient:prez, amount:precalc, unit:prem}]
      }}
  );
}
```

I precalculated the new value and used $set because apparently the $mul operator isn't working with meteor. This solution partly works, but unfortunately it overwrites all ingredients and only multiplies the last one (which is obvious). There must be a much simpler way to do that - I just didn't find it. I'm new to MongoDB and Meteor so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about updating the collection with all of the ingredients after the loop (collecting the in an array during the loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't execute an update for each ingredient, only one for the entire document. I'd do something like this:

```
let newIngredients = this.ingredients.map(x => {
  ingredient: x.ingredient,
  amount: x.amount * 1.5,
  unit: x.unit
});

Recipes.update(
  {_id: this._id},
  {$set: {ingredients: newIngredients}}
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was easy. Unfortunately the fat arrow syntax didn't work but I'll ended up with creating a newIngredients array and updating the Collection once. Works perfectly!